# Fast method to verify if a point belongs to a given convex $d$-polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, algorithms, discrete-geometry, computational-complexity

We are given a $d$-dimensional convex polytope $P\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume we have all the supporting hyperplanes describing $P$ and its vertices. Let $S$ be a sequence of $n\gg 1$ points $\mathbb{R}^d$ that we obtain one after the other in an online fashion. For the sake of simplicity, assume that $d$ is much smaller than the number of vertices and hyperplanes describing $P$.

**Questions:**

Is there any (potentially very time consuming) pre-computation of $P$ that enables us to *quickly* verify if each point $\mathbf{p}\in S$ belongs to $P$ (even using a *randomized* test technique to obtain *approximate* membership result, i.e., assuming that the probability of making a testing mistake is not $0$ while having an efficient *expected* time complexity for each test)?

In general, what are the characteristics of $P$ on which the test time complexity depends?

---

---

***My conjecture:*** *Let $V$ and $H$ be the vertex and hyperplane set respectively used in input to describe $P$. For any given convex $d$-polytope $P$, it should be possible pre-compute a set of points $S_p$ and hyperplanes $S_h$ with $|S_p|, |S_h| \ll |V|, |H|$, such that we can test (at least approximately) if each point $\mathbf{p}\in S$ belongs to $P$ by calculating ***only*** the distances between $\mathbf{p}$ and some of the points and hyperplanes respectively in $S_p$ with $S_h$.*

Comment: This is equivalent to solving a set of linear inequalities, because if $P$ is affinely generated by points $p_1,\dots,p_n$, then the point $p$ will be in $P$ iff there is no vector $v$ with $v\cdot(p_n-p)>0\;\forall p$ (because if $p$ is not in $P$, there is a hyperplane separating them due to $P$ being convex). So probably there will be nothing better than the usual methods from linear programming

Comment: Thank you @SaúlRodríguezMartín . I thought that maybe there was some clever randomized algorithm (using rejection sampling?) whose *expected* time complexity is better than the one of the classical approach. For instance, if $P$ is a ***very*** (arbitrarily) good approximation of a $d$-ball, I think that there must be a better approach to avoid an arbitrarily large time complexity.

Comment: Does it not also depend quite a bit on how your convex polytope P is presented? Converting between the convex-hull-of-pts description, and the supporting hyperplane-description also takes lots of computational effort, so I think you must specify exactly what data you are assumed to know about P.

Comment: Thank you @PerAlexandersson . I added these details to the question.

Comment: If you have the list of hyperplanes, you can just test the sign of each hyperplane on your point. Whether or not this is a better idea than linear programming will presumably depend on the details of your polytope.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidESpeyer , I know, but I also suspect a faster (maybe randomized) method exists. For instance, perhaps it is possible to build a data structure based on $P$ such that *any* ***new*** point we need to test requires a better *expected* time. Again, I am thinking about the general case where, for instance, $P$ is a very (arbitrarily) good approximation of a $d$-ball (I think that there must be a better approach to avoid an arbitrarily large time complexity).

Comment: If you have a list of hyperplanes and your points tend to be close to each other, then I would argue that you may want to (occasionally?) order the hyperplanes according to the values at the points and then first look at the ones that were close to flipping to the outside.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: If you have a lot of points you want to check with the same polytope, you can put them into a matrix; computing AX>b*(1,1,1,1) batched together can potentially be faster because of matrix multiplication algorithms. But that's not online; maybe there's some online algorithm that can possibly take advantage of the same kind of speedup?

Comment: Thank you @LevBorisov, yes, but there are not assumptions about the stream of points $S$.

Comment: Thank you @qwyxivi . Yes, I am looking for an online method working for stream of unknown points. Maybe it is possible to arrange the information about $P$ to avoid checking all hyperplanes inequalities. Perhaps we can cluster together beforehand the hyperplanes describing $P$ to easily find the ones "almost parallel" to any given hyperplane and exploit the calculation of some distances between any new point in $S$ and some specific vertices of $P$.

Comment: On similar lines, if you have a "narrow" dimension then it makes sense to check that first, so maybe something like principal components analysis would help calculate bounding boxes to give quick-reject and quick-accept with $|S_p|=2d$?

Comment: Thank you, @PeterTaylor . I thought of something similar, but I cannot formalize it yet. Anyway, I think it would be a great result to solve this problem even under the assumption $d \ll |V|$. 
In any case, I am viewing this problem as allowing the pre-computation process to have a very large time complexity, i.e., I am not demanding a fast pre-computation, only a fast test verification per point in $S$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Anyway, even assuming $d\ll |V|$, $d$ could be large enough so that the volume the bounding box can be much larger than the one of $P$.

Comment: Do you know the computational geometry literature on similar problems? For example, see https://doi.org/10.1137/0209028.

Comment: Thank you very much @domotorp !